ML.NET mix forecast and predict
I am making simple app for detection network anomalies in .NET
App is collecting raw packets, then analizes it and determines whether potential attack has occured (with static algoritm). For now, i've implemented algorithm to detect tcp flood attack based on SYN and ACK flags in tcp packets. Besides analyzing, app is saving data in a file in specified schema:
SOURCE_IP | DESTINATION_IP | TIMESTAMP (TIMEVAL) | SYN | ACK
10.0.0.5  | 10.0.0.10      | 1726332243,275925   | 1   | 1

I want to implement ML model (with ML.NET) that forecast and predict that whether attack occured, based on data that has been already collected in current "session".
I tried with adding another column "IsAttack" that was my label. After that i simulated tcp flood attack and prepared data for training by completing the last column. But ml model also includes that previous labels which are all "0" in current session, so it doesnt work properly. On the other hand, when i tried predict scenario, ML takes data only from single row. Any idea how can i mix predict and forecast? Or any other solution?
Generated ML Model:
public partial class TCPFloodMLDetector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// model input class for TCPFloodMLDetector.
    /// </summary>
    #region model input class
    public class ModelInput
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        public string SourceAddress { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(1)]
        public string DestinationAddress { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(2)]
        public double Timeval { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(3)]
        public bool SYN { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(4)]
        public bool ACK { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(5)]
        [ColumnName(@"col5")]
        public Single IsAttack { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// model output class for TCPFloodMLDetector.
    /// </summary>
    #region model output class
    public class ModelOutput
    {
        [ColumnName(@"col5")]
        public float[] Col5 { get; set; }

        [ColumnName(@"col5_LB")]
        public float[] Col5_LB { get; set; }

        [ColumnName(@"col5_UB")]
        public float[] Col5_UB { get; set; }

    }

    #endregion

    private static string MLNetModelPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"D:\Projects\NetworkAnalyzer\\Models\TCPFloodMLDetector.mlnet");

    public static readonly Lazy<TimeSeriesPredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>> PredictEngine = new Lazy<TimeSeriesPredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>>(() => CreatePredictEngine(), true);

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this method to predict on <see cref="ModelInput"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">model input.</param>
    /// <returns><seealso cref=" ModelOutput"/></returns>
    public static ModelOutput Predict(ModelInput? input = null, int? horizon = null)
    {
        var predEngine = PredictEngine.Value;
        return predEngine.Predict(input, horizon);
    }

    private static TimeSeriesPredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput> CreatePredictEngine()
    {
        var mlContext = new MLContext();
        ITransformer mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load(MLNetModelPath, out var schema);
        return mlModel.CreateTimeSeriesEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(mlContext);
    }
}

Im using this in Detect function that runs every second:
public async Task Detect()
{
    try
    {
        var context = new MLContext();
        var data = context.Data.LoadFromTextFile<TCPFloodInputModel>("tcpflood.txt",
            hasHeader: false, separatorChar: '|');

        TCPFloodMLDetector.LoadIDataViewFromFile(context, "tcpflood.txt",
            '|', false, true);

        // predict with default option.
        var modelOutput = TCPFloodMLDetector.Predict();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", modelOutput.Col5));

        // predict next 5 periods
        modelOutput = TCPFloodMLDetector.Predict(horizon: 5);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", modelOutput.Col5));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}

